# rabbitmq-management plugin HTTP API - Security concerns

Tags: security, http, rabbitmq

I want to enable RabbitMQ Management plugin on my production environment, but I'm not sure about the security concerns this might bring.
I already have a few applications connected to the RMQ, and hence can't change the credentials now (I'm using default).

Could anyone shed some light on this? I want to know what all things I might need to worry about and what I could do to minimise vulnerabilities.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Management Plugin use **credentials**, which is enough for most cases unless you want it to be accessible from outside. At this case **iptables** is your friend. In addition you can **proxy** HTTP api and management interface via nginx (or apache) and use additional security layer like basic auth.

If you are a bit paranoid (like me) you can **combine all 3 methods** to have more protection (and have non-trivial access to your management interface from non-usual locations like free wifi zone in airport when flow control get applied ont your server, but this is quite unusual situation).

**UPD:**

**Note:** if your application is badly-designed and mix routine job with management job under same account you may get into some troubles. I suggest you [management plugin Permission section](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#permissions) for further reading.

Usually, separate account for application and management job, as well as disabling default guest account (for outside only or in general) is the best choice from security point of view.

If you are forced to use default `guest` account you can disable management plugin for it and create separate account for administration only. In fact in recent RabbitMQ version it is disabled for accessing from outside.

To do this, firs create administration user (account with `administrator` tag), make sure it works and then update `guest` use by removing all tags it has (actually, removing `administrator` tag is the only one set by default for `guest` account).

Here is a pic of default `guest` account with note what to remove.

[image: Tag location to remove]

Comment: Thanks! As for credentials, I am using default username and password, and can't really change this now since apps use them - added this to my question. And iptables, yes, that was one thing I was thinking of too as well.

Comment: You can disable management plugin for default guest/guest (in fact in recent RabbitMQ version it is disabled for accessing from outside) and create separate account for administration only.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to disable the plugin for guest. Could you help me out?

Comment: Upd my answer with a brief howto. But it would be more secure to just use separate account for application and management tasks and don't stick with guest at all.

Comment: If I remove admin tag for guest, will it not impact the applications using it? I mean, won't it mean that guest user can't create queues, etc?

Comment: Sure it will not prevent user without admin tag to create queues, exchanges, etc., unless you implicitly disable that - see configure, write and read regexp for more.